# Excel web view broken in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, microsoft-excel

Last night I patched and rebooted our SharePoint 2010 server. Everything looked fine but this morning the Excel web viewer is broken. When trying to open a spreadsheet I get an error box stating, "Unable to process request.  Wait a few minutes and try performing this operation again."

The Excel Calculation Service is running, the Application Pool is running and using a valid domain account, and I've even reinstalled the Excel Services Application.

Any other suggestions as to how to get this functional again?

Logs:

```
07/06/2012 16:09:44.24  w3wp.exe (0x1F50)                           0x10D8  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mc    Medium      WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://server:9999/{id}/ExcelService.asmx' Channel: 'Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.Proxy.IExcelServiceSoap' Action: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/Excel/Server/WebServices/ExcelServerInternalService/ExcelServiceSoap/GetHealthScore' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:{id}'  {id}
07/06/2012 16:09:44.24  w3wp.exe (0x1F50)                           0x10D8  Excel Services Application      Web Front End                   acbd    Critical    Unable to reach Excel Calculation Services http://server:9999/{id}/ExcelService*.asmx. [Session:  User: DOMAIN\user]    {id}
07/06/2012 16:09:44.24  w3wp.exe (0x1F50)                           0x10D8  Excel Services Application      Web Front End                   accf    Medium      ServerSession.ProcessWebException: A Web exception during ExecuteWebMethod has occurred for server: http://server:9999/{id}/ExcelService*.asmx, method: GetHealthScore, ex: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout), response: 'System.Net.HttpWebResponse', status ProtocolError, user name: DOMAIN\user.   {id}
07/06/2012 16:09:44.24  w3wp.exe (0x1F50)                           0x10D8  Excel Services Application      Web Front End                   acco    Critical    There was an error in communicating with Excel Calculation Services http://server:9999/{id}/ExcelService*.asmx exception: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable. [Session:  User: DOMAIN\user]. {id} 2159   Critical    Event 5231 (Excel Services Application) of severity 'Error' occurred 10 more time(s) and was suppressed in the event log     
07/06/2012 16:09:44.38  w3wp.exe (0x1F50)                           0x1248  SharePoint Server               Unified Logging Service         2159    Critical    Event 5239 (Excel Services Application) of severity 'Error' occurred 10 more time(s) and was suppressed in the event log     
07/06/2012 16:09:46.55  w3wp.exe (0x1D04)                           0x2670  SharePoint Foundation           Topology
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oddly enough, I resolved the issue with a simple restart. It had a clean reboot the day before after being patched so I was very skeptical that it would help, but it did.

Here's the article with the explanation: [Error communicating with Excel Services Application - Events 5231 5239 5240](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513104.aspx)